# Java generics - Map with generic type as key

Tags: java, generics

I have following maps. Both maps hold instance of `ClassA/ClassB` and instance of `CellProcessor` as value.

```
Map<ClassA, CellProcessor> classAProcessors;
Map<ClassB, CellProcessor> classBProcessors;
```

I want to create a map which will store above maps as value and with key as class type of `ClassA/ClassB` so that when I do `map.get(ClassA.class)` it returns me `Map<ClassA, CellProcessor> classAProcessors`

I wrote this method to create final map but it does not seem to be working.

```
public static <T> Map<Class<T>, Map<T, CellProcessor>> getOutputProcessors(){
    Map<ClassA, CellProcessor> classAProcessors = getOutputCellProcessorsForClassA();
    Map<Class<T>, Map<T, CellProcessor>> processors = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    processors.put(ClassA.class, classAProcessors ); //error here
    return processors;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
The method put(Class<T>, Map<T,CellProcessor>) in the type Map<Class<T>,Map<T,CellProcessor>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ClassA>, Map<ClassA,CellProcessor>)
```

Could someone help me in understanding what's wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: What is not working, precisely? Are you getting an error, or is the behaviour unexpected?

Comment: added compiler error message

Comment: `T` is not necessarily `ClassA`, but that's what you are trying to force.

Comment: `ClassA/ClassB` are enums.

Comment: You're not going to be able to make this work in a type-safe manner.  Java's type system isn't strong enough to express the kind of constraints you're trying to express.

Comment: Is there any safe workaround? I see that compiler error is gone if I do typecasting suggested by eclipse but not sure if thats' right way to go. Was hoping to save duplicate code with this approach.

Comment: Why not create a `Map<Class<?>, CellProcessor> classProcessor` map?

Comment: Your approach seems a bit off. What, in plain English, is your intention?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler reports an error because you are trying to add to the map `processors` an entry with an incompatible type. At compile time the compiler does not know what the type of `T` is. Type `T` will be determined by the client which uses the method `getOutputProcessors`. Method `processors.put` expects that the first parameter is exactly the type of `Class<T>` (`T` will be determined only by code that uses the method `getOutputProcessors`), but you are always passing the same value of `ClassA.class`. The second parameter of the method `processors.put` is also incorrect, it should be exactly the type of `Map<T, CellProcessor>`, and you are passing permanently argument of type `Map<ClassA, CellProcessor>`. Treat type `T` as an independent type, so in the code of your method `T` is not equivalent to `ClassA`. The correct version of your method should look like this:

```
public static <T> Map<Class<T>, Map<T, CellProcessor>> getOutputProcessors(Class<T> key, Map<T, CellProcessor> classProcessors) {
    Map<Class<T>, Map<T, CellProcessor>> processors = new HashMap<Class<T>, Map<T, CellProcessor>>();
    processors.put(key, classProcessors);
    return processors;
}
```

You can use this method in the following manner:

```
Map<Class<ClassA>, Map<ClassA, CellProcessor>> processorsA = getOutputProcessors(ClassA.class, classAProcessors);
Map<Class<ClassB>, Map<ClassB, CellProcessor>> processorsB = getOutputProcessors(ClassB.class, classBProcessors);
```

But in this way the map `processorsA` and `processorsB` are not compatible and you will not be able to merge them into one map. So you need to use different type of map than `Map<Class<T>, Map<T, CellProcessor>>`.
The best way is to create (or not if it already exists) a super type for `ClassA` and `ClassB` (for example a class or interface with name `ClassBase`). `getOutputProcessors` method that uses superclass `ClassBase` looks as follows:

```
public static Map<Class<? extends ClassBase>, Map<? extends ClassBase, CellProcessor>> getOutputProcessors() {
    Map<Class<? extends ClassBase>, Map<? extends ClassBase, CellProcessor>> processors = 
            new HashMap<Class<? extends ClassBase>, Map<? extends ClassBase, CellProcessor>>();

    processors.put(ClassA.class, getOutputCellProcessorsForClassA());
    processors.put(ClassB.class, getOutputCellProcessorsForClassB());

    return processors;
}
```

If for some reason you can not have in your code superclass ClassBase then you can use a method that looks as follows:

```
public static Map<Class<? extends Object>, Map<? extends Object, CellProcessor>> getOutputProcessors3() {
    Map<Class<? extends Object>, Map<? extends Object, CellProcessor>> processors = 
            new HashMap<Class<? extends Object>, Map<? extends Object, CellProcessor>>();

    processors.put(ClassA.class, getOutputCellProcessorsForClassA());
    processors.put(ClassB.class, getOutputCellProcessorsForClassB());

    return processors;
}
```

I hope my answer will help you

Answer (score 1):

ClassA and ClassB cannot be in the same typed map. To do this you will need a map that is heterogenous (can have objects of any type) and as such it will need to be a HashMap with no type arguments (or ? or Object as an argument).

However, if ClassA and ClassB share the same supertype, then you can make a map for that shared supertype.

No if I am misunderstanding and you just want a map of maps for classA separate from classB then you need two methods. You can't overload implementations with generics the way you can with C++ templates.

So you will need to methods with different names one returning the map of maps for ClassA and the other for ClassB. They can't have the same name and be in the same class but specialized for different types.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding `<T>`, class is enough.

If at all you want to use `<T>` change it to  and have ClassA and ClassB extends baseClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<Class, Map<Object, CellProcessor>> getOutputProcessors() {
    Map<Class, Map<Object, CellProcessor>> processors = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    processors.put(ClassA.class, getOutputCellProcessorsForClassA);
    return processors;
}
```